# php test framework compare arrays

Tags: testing

I have been trying to learn pestphp testing framework. So I have setup a test to test a validation class I use but it always returns:

> " INFO  TEST1Array ( [0] => Array ( [form_err] => password: Password must contain 6 characters of letters, numbers and at least one special character. ) [1] => Array ( [form_err] => password: Password should be minimum minLen:8 characters ) ) Failed asserting that an array has a key 0 with the value Array (…). Failed asserting that two arrays are equal."

So the assertion using toMatchArray always fails.

This is the code I use:

```
<?php
include '../../test/validator.php';

echo 'TEST1';
$v = new  Validator();
$a =  array('password' => '1' );
$b =  [  'password' =>  ['good_password' , 'minLen:8' ]  ];
$r = $v->validate($a, $b );
$e=$v->error();
print_r($e);

expect( $e )->toMatchArray(
         ['0'   => ['form_err'  => "password: Password must contain 6 characters of letters, numbers and at least one special character." ],
         '1'   => ['form_err'  => "password: Password should be minimum minLen:8 characters" ],
        ]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem with your test code is in the assertion statement. The error message suggests that the assertion is failing because the expected array does not have a **key 0** with the value of an array.

To fix this, you can try to change your assertion statement to something like this:

```
expect($e)->toMatchArray(
[        ['form_err' => "password: Password must contain 6 characters of letters, numbers and at least one special character."],
    ['form_err' => "password: Password should be minimum minLen:8 characters"],
]
);
```

This way, you're asserting that the array **$e** should match an array with two elements, each containing the **form_err** key with the expected error message.I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer but no it still says the same if you remove the 0 and 1

Comment: try modifying your assertion to check for the specific error messages that are being returned by the validation class. Here's an example:
expect( $e[0]['form_err'] )->toBe("password: Password must contain 6 characters of letters, numbers and at least one special character.");
expect( $e[1]['form_err'] )->toBe("password: Password should be minimum minLen:8 characters");